# Can I say musician present or in the presence of the musicians

Tags: word-usage

> It was not possible for me to realize the performance with the musicians present.

Can I say musician present or in the presence of the musicians

Comment: Yes. you can, but "realize" the performance is an easy indication of non-native English.  It's how my Brazilian wife would say it. What are you actually doing?

Comment: sing with musicians

Comment: Idiomatically, we would just say "It was not possible for me to perform with the musicians present.

Comment: 'In the presence of...' is fine as well.